expo run project on both mobile and tablet emulators
What exactly is the workflow to be able to run and test the expo project on both android mobile and tablet emulators.
I have following devices running
adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device
emulator-5556   device

Attempt
package.json is
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "android-tablet": "adb -s emulator-5556 install $(expo build:android -t apk)",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },


Or suggest a better workflow approach to test on both please, I'm new to development in expo.
